# Does link/rm/mv sync dentry metadata immediately when finished?

Tags: linux, inode, ext4

Does link/rm/mv sync dentry metadata to permanent storage immediately when finished? If not, when?

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt, I get this:

> drop_caches
>
> Writing to this will cause the kernel to drop clean caches, as well as
> reclaimable slab objects like dentries and inodes.  Once dropped,
> their memory becomes free.
>
> To free pagecache:
>
> > echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
>
> To free reclaimable slab objects (includes dentries and inodes):
>
> > echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
>
> To free slab objects and pagecache:
>
> > echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
>
> This is a non-destructive operation and will not free any dirty
> objects. To increase the number of objects freed by this operation,
> the user may run `sync' prior to writing to /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches.
> This will minimize the number of dirty objects on the system and
> create more candidates to be dropped.
>
> This file is not a means to control the growth of the various kernel
> caches (inodes, dentries, pagecache, etc...)  These objects are
> automatically reclaimed by the kernel when memory is needed elsewhere
> on the system.
>
> Use of this file can cause performance problems.  Since it discards
> cached objects, it may cost a significant amount of I/O and CPU to
> recreate the dropped objects, especially if they were under heavy use.
> Because of this, use outside of a testing or debugging environment is
> not recommended.
>
> You may see informational messages in your kernel log when this file
> is used:
>
> cat (1234): drop_caches: 3
>
> These are informational only.  They do not mean that anything is wrong
> with your system.  To disable them, echo 4 (bit 3) into drop_caches.